# Sample N points from a set of 3D points that maximizes the minimum distance

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, numpy

Say I have 500 random 3D points represented by a `(500, 3)` array:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(99)
points = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (500, 3))
```

Now I want to sample `n = 20` points from these 500 points, so that the minimum value of all pairwise distances is the largest. I am using a greedy approach that samples the point that maximizes the minimum distance each time. Below is my Python implementation:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

def sample_n_points(points, n):
    sampled_points = [points[0]]
    remained_points = points[1:]
    n_sampled = 1

    while n_sampled < n:
        min_dists = distance_matrix(remained_points, sampled_points).min(axis=1)
        imax = np.argmax(min_dists)
        sampled_points.append(remained_points[imax])
        np.delete(remained_points, (imax), axis=0)
        n_sampled += 1

    return np.asarray(sampled_points)

print(sample_n_points(points, n=20))
```

Output:

```
[[6.72278559 4.88078399 8.25495174]
 [1.01317279 9.74063145 0.15102072]
 [5.21672436 0.39259574 0.1069965 ]
 [9.89383494 9.77095442 1.15681204]
 [0.77144184 9.99325146 9.8976312 ]
 [0.04558333 2.34842151 5.25634324]
 [9.58126175 0.57371576 5.01765991]
 [9.93010888 9.959526   9.18606297]
 [5.27648557 9.93960401 4.82093673]
 [2.97622499 0.46695721 9.90627399]
 [0.28351187 3.64220133 0.06793617]
 [6.27527665 5.58177254 0.3544929 ]
 [0.4861886  7.45547887 5.342708  ]
 [0.83203965 5.00400167 9.40102603]
 [5.21120971 2.89966623 4.24236342]
 [9.18165946 0.26450445 9.58031481]
 [5.47605481 9.4493094  9.94331621]
 [9.31058632 6.36970353 5.33362741]
 [9.47554604 2.31761252 1.53774694]
 [3.99460408 6.17908899 6.00786122]]
```

However, by using this code, an optimal solution is not guaranteed. The most obvious "mistake" of my code is that it always starts by sampling the first point. Of course I can run my code using each point as the starting point and finally take the one that maximizes the minimum distance, but even that won't give the optimal solution. The points are very apart from each other in the beginning, but are forced to be close to each other as more points are sampled. After some thought, I realize this problem essentially becomes

> finding the subset in a set of 3D points that most evenly distributed.

I want to know if there is any algorithm that can find the optimal solution or give a good approximation relatively fast?

**Edit**

The decision problem version of this optimization problem would be:

> given a distance threshold *t*, whether it is possible to find a subset of n points such that every pair of points in the subset are at least *t* apart.

In a graph point of view, this can be intepreted as

> finding an independent set in a Euclidean graph, where points *v1, v2* have an edge between them if the pairwise distance *d*(*v1,v2*) ≤ *t*.

If we can solve this decision problem, then the optimization problem can also be solved by a binary search on the threshold *t*.

Comment: So you're trying to find the 20 most distant points?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes you can understand it like this

Comment: You could use an iterative algorithm; start with 20 random points; then for each point, compute in what direction to move it to get it as far as possible from the other points. Repeat until the system stabilizes. Or alternatively, start with 20 random points; then for each point, nudge it by a small step away from its closest point. Repeat until the system stabilizes.

Comment: True optimum - not that I know of. But you probably get decent results on 'reasonable' data sets using random search approaches. For example: start with 20 random point. Choose one at random, and replace it with the point from the rest of the collection which minimizes your cost function. Repeat until no more improvement or max iterations.

Comment: I am afraid that this sounds like an NP-hard problem, but I am not sure. If so, your best bet is essentially to go on a randomized algorithm that "most of the time" provides a "good enough" solution. However, you could also ask this on CS stackexchange, where there are probably more people that could provide a more specific and/or helpful answer.

Comment: As an aside, since it's not exactly your question, but do you think a fast and exact solution to the same problem, but that tries to minimize the mean distance between selected points, would be acceptable? In this case, I think I could have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some illuminating comments, I recognise the exact solution is intractable for even moderate problem sizes.

One possible approximate solution uses K-means clustering. Here is an example in 2D so I can include a plot.

```
np.random.seed(99)
n = 500
k = 20
pts2D = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (n, 2))

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0).fit(pts2D)
labels = kmeans.predict(pts2D)
cntr = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Now we can find which of the original points is nearest to each cluster centre:

```
# indices of nearest points to centres
approx = []

for i, c in enumerate(cntr):
    lab = np.where(labels == i)[0]
    pts = pts2D[lab]
    d = distance_matrix(c[None, ...], pts)
    idx1 = np.argmin(d, axis=1) + 1
    idx2 = np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(labels == i), idx1)[0]
    approx.append(idx2)
```

Then, we can plot the result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.plot(pts2D[:, 0], pts2D[:, 1], '.')
ax.plot(cntr[:, 0], cntr[:, 1], 'x')
ax.plot(pts2D[approx, 0], pts2D[approx, 1], 'r.')
ax.set_aspect("equal")
fig.legend(["points", "centres", "selected"], loc=1)
```

[image: plot of results]

Finally, if the real points are always uniformly distributed, you could get a good approximation by uniformly placing "centres" and selecting the nearest point to each. There would then be no need for K-means.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I have understood your requirements.

Following on from your start:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(99)
points = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (500, 3))
```

You should get the distance between **all** points and sort on the distance:

```
# get distances between all points
d = distance_matrix(points, points)
# zero the identical upper triangle
dt = np.tril(d)
# list the distances and their indexes
dtv = [(dt[i, j], i, j) for (i, j) in np.argwhere(dt > 0)]
# sort the list
dtvs = sorted(dtv, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Then you can grow a `set` to get the 20 indices to points that contribute to the greatest distances.

**Edit** to limit the result to `k` unique point indices.

```
kpoint_index = set()
k = 20
i = 0

for p in (j for i in dtvs for j in i[1:]):
    kpoint_index.add(p)
    if len(kpoint_index) == k:
        break

print("index to points:", kpoint_index)
```

giving:

```
index to points: {393, 11, 282, 415, 160, 302, 189, 319, 194, 453, 73, 74, 459, 335, 469, 221, 103, 232, 236, 383}
```

This runs pretty quickly - but I did not time it.

Comment: I'm afraid sampling from the most distant points will result in a minimum distance lower than if I sample points more averagely.

Comment: Hi @ShaunHan, because we calculate all distances, sort them, and select the points that form the largest distances, you are guaranteed to have the largest distribution. The only question is how to select the points? Each distance needs 2 points, and I think you want unique points in your selection. If you allow duplicates you could have greater total distance. Think of an outlier way to the side of most of the points. That one outlier would be one of the pairs of all the larger distances.

Comment: The thing is, I want to have greater minimum distance, not greater total distance. Think it this way: if we have four 1D points like ``[1, 3, 6, 10]`` and we want to choose a subset of 3 points. The subset chosen by your logic would be ``[1, 3, 10]``, which gives the largest total distance of ``3-1 + 10-1 + 10-3 = 18``, but a minimum distance of ``3-1 = 2``. However if I choose a subset of e.g. ``[3, 6, 10]``, I will have a smaller total distance of ``6-3 + 10-3 + 10-6 = 14``, but a larger minimum distance of ``6-3 = 3``. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it really illustrated well your problem. I decided to create a separate answer, as the suggested solution is quite different.